# How to fix 404 while fetching

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, fetch-api

I am working on a simple API project from openweather API and making my own project, however I got stuck when I try to fetch data from the API I am getting a `404` error.

This is my code:

```
async function fetchData(cityName) {
  const API_KEY = 'MY_API_KEY';

  const fethRes = await fetch(
    `api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityName}&appid=${API_KEY}`,
    {
      mode: 'cors',
    }
  );
}
```

and this is the error I got:

> GEThttp://127.0.0.1:5500/dist/api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=paris&appid={MY_API_KEY}

For security reasons I hide my API key, hope you understand:)

Comment: Try 'https://' instead of 'api.'.  Or, maybe you need to leave 'api.' just add 'https://' in front.

Comment: @CharlesEF still facing same issue

Comment: Fetch is using your url as the domain.  You need to do `fetch(https://api.openweathermap.org/......)`.

Comment: @StevenB. still facing same issue should i provide some snapshots of error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**, I've tested the code and it's working now

```
async function fetchData(cityName) {
  const API_KEY = 'Your_API_KEY';

const fethRes =  {
  method: 'GET',
  redirect: 'manual'
};

await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityName}&appid=${API_KEY}`, fethRes)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}
```